# jdbc -PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time:{1}

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem while doing a select on a date field in my web application.
I've defined data in this way:

```
Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateTemp2 = dateFormat2.format(data.getTime());
    risultato_vendita = bean.inserimento_vendita(scontrino,data,prodotto1, quantita1);
```

In the DB data_vendita is a Date field not null. After insert, I see dates like this by doing a select in pgadmin: 2017-04-20

This is the function who make the select:

```
public int inserimento_vendita(int scontrino, Date data, String prodotto, int quantita) throws eccezione {

        int risultato = 0;
        String insert = "INSERT INTO farmacia.vendita (id, data_vendita, prodotto, quantita) "+
                        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try 
        {
            connect();
            stmt = getStatement(insert);
            stmt.setInt(1, scontrino);
            stmt.setDate(2, data);
            stmt.setString(3, prodotto);
            stmt.setInt(4, quantita);
            risultato = executeUpdate(stmt);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n--- SQLException catturata ---\n");
            Logger.getLogger(SessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                stmt.close();
                close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)  
            {
                Logger.getLogger(SessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
        return risultato;

    }
```

I've got this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {1}
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.parseBackendTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:358)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.toTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:390)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.toDate(TimestampUtils.java:468)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getDate(PgResultSet.java:516)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getDate(PgResultSet.java:2378)
        at session.SessionBean.lista_vendite(SessionBean.java:1030)
        at org.apache.jsp.report_jsp._jspService(report_jsp.java:83)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected time to be colon-separated, got '
```

this is the table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE vendita (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    prodotto character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    data_vendita date NOT NULL,
    quantita integer NOT NULL
);
```

EDIT: lista_vendite

```
<%
SessionBean b = new SessionBean();

List<Vendita> lista_vendite = b.lista_vendite();
```

%>

```
<table class="myTable">
         <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codice</th>
      <th>Prodotto</th>
    <th>Data</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>         
             <%


        for(Vendita e: lista_vendite){  

        out.print("<tr><td>"+e.getVenditaPK()+"</td><td>"+e.getQuantita()+"</td><td>"+e.getDataVendita()+"</td></tr>");


}

        %>
  </tbody>
     </table>
```

EDIT: lista_vendite method

```
public List<Vendita> lista_vendite() throws eccezione{

        int risultato = 0;
        VenditaPK venditaPK;
        List<Vendita> lista = new ArrayList<Vendita>();

        String select = "SELECT * FROM farmacia.vendita";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;

        try 
        {
            connect();
            stmt = getStatement(select);
            res = executeQuery(stmt);
             while(res.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Iterazione");
                Vendita d1 = new Vendita();
                venditaPK = new VenditaPK();
                d1.setDataVendita(res.getDate(1));
                d1.setQuantita(res.getInt(2));

                venditaPK.setId(res.getInt("id"));
                venditaPK.setProdotto(res.getString("prodotto"));
                d1.setVenditaPK(venditaPK);
                lista.add(d1);
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(SessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                stmt.close();
                res.close();
                close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(SessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return lista;


}
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't match the code in the exception stacktrace. You should also include the DDL of the table involved. Given the stacktrace, it looks like your column contains the string `{1}` instead of a date (or a date string), although it could also be a message parametrization bug in the driver.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I've added the table declaration in the db, anyway the column contains the date, I've checked that by pgadmin, but here I can't get the date, I don't know why

Comment: I think you've found a bug in the JDBC driver itself. In `TimestampUtils.parseBackendTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:358)` the row with `GT.tr("Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {1}", str)` should really be `GT.tr("Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {0}", str)` (this current way won't report any useful information, ever)...

Comment: You still haven't addressed the first part of my comment: the code shown is of method `inserimento_vendita`, your exception occurs in method `lista_vendite`. You might also want to specify the PostgreSQL version and the version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've added lista_vendite code, Iim using PostgreSQL 9.6 and postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar

Comment: @Nicola that's not the code of the `lista_vendite` method. Please provide that (the JSP fragment seems irrelevant anyway)

Comment: @pozs sorry, I've added the code right now

Comment: @Nicola if your `CREATE TABLE` is correct (and also the **order** is right in it), than you are trying to parse the `id` column as a date, which will never work. Either supply the column names in your select & use the  getters (of `ResultSet`) with the `int` argument **or** use `*` (for all columns) and use the getters with the `String` argument. It is usually a bad practice to rely on column ordering anyway.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding, why I'm trying to parse id column as a date? I've used setInt for that field.. @pozs

Comment: @Nicola `res.getDate(1)` -- the first column in your table is `id`

Comment: omg, thank you mate, I've got another problem now with another column.
In the same table, pks are id and prodotto. Netbeans made 2 entities, Vendita and VenditaPK. As you can see in lista_vendite, I've made an object venditaPK to store both pks, how can retrieve them in the table that you can see in the first post? I have to replace e.getVenditaPK() with something other @pozs

Comment: I've solved that by myself, thanks for all, if you'll post as an answer I'll accept it! @pozs